# Hibernate SQL Error: Missing FROM-clause entry for table "th1_1"

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm encountering an issue with Hibernate where I'm getting the following SQL error:

Please help me to resolve error

SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "th1_1"
Position: 14

I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I'm using Hibernate for ORM mapping. I have entities defined for dx_entity and dx_temporary_hazard, and I'm using a join strategy inheritance between them.
I'm attempting to retrieve data using Hibernate's findAll method.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "dx_entity")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "table_name", discriminatorType = 
 DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Where(clause = "deleted_at is null")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DxEntity extends MultiTenantEntity implements Serializable 
{
    // Entity fields...
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "dx_temporary_hazard")
@Setter
@Getter
@DiscriminatorValue("dx_temporary_hazard")
public class TemporaryHazard extends DxEntity {
         // Entity fields...
}

  @RestController
    public class TController {
        private final TemporaryHazardRepository 
        temporaryHazardRepository;

        public TController(TemporaryHazardRepository 
          temporaryHazardRepository) {
            this.temporaryHazardRepository = temporaryHazardRepository;
        }

        @GetMapping("/test")
        public Page<TemporaryHazard> test() {
            return 
         temporaryHazardRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,20));
        }
    }
```

When we trigger /test controller, Quires performed in console:

```
`SELECT th1_1.pk_id,
       th1_0.changed_at,
       th1_0.changed_by,
       th1_0.created_at,
       th1_0.created_by,
       th1_0.created_layout,
       th1_0.deleted_at,
       th1_0.module_name,
       th1_0.status,
       th1_0.tag,
       th1_0.tenant_id,
       th1_0.updated_layout,
       th1_1.abc,
       th1_1.xyz,
       th1_1.abc1,
       th1_1.control_measures_required,
       th1_1.xyz1,
       th1_1.type
FROM   PUBLIC.dx_entity th1_0
JOIN   PUBLIC.dx_temporary_hazard th1_1
ON     th1_0.pk_id=th1_1.pk_id
WHERE  th1_0.tenant_id = ?
AND    (
              th1_0.deleted_at IS NULL)
AND    th1_0.table_name='dx_temporary_hazard' offset ? rowsFETCH first ? rows only`
```

`SELECT count(th1_1.pk_id) FROM   PUBLIC.dx_entity th1_0 WHERE  th1_0.tenant_id = ? AND    ( th1_0.deleted_at IS NULL) AND    th1_0.table_name='dx_temporary_hazard'`

**Error:**
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

We can see that "th1_1.pk_id" is wrong alias name in count query. Hence query failing to return result.
I tried with hibernate 6.2.x and 6.4.x version, No luck